# CNN architecture for computer vision

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement this [paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~urtasun/publications/luo_etal_cvpr18.pdf) using Tensorflow. The authors are using a modified version of VGG 16:

> ...We then perform convolution and max-pooling following VGG16 with each layer number of feature maps reduced by half.

but modifying it as follow:

> Note that we remove the last convolution group in VGG16, resulting in only 10 convolution layers.

so they are replacing the last 6 layers (3 convolutional layers and 3 fully connected layers) of the typical VGG16 architecture with two convolutional layers one for binary classification and the other for bounding boxes prediction:

> We then add two branches of convolution layers as shown in Fig. 5. The first one performs binary classification to predict the probability of being a vehicle. The second one predicts the bounding box over the current frame as well as n−1 frames into the future.

The issue is that I'm stuck for quite some time now figuring out how to implement these two layers. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Some of most popular networks are already in python libraries. vgg-16 is the implemented in python so you can import it in your script and use pre-trained vgg weights or only use vgg stracture and also you can use every part of network. so search for python libraries which contains popular networks such as vgg.